# Pushing commit to github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I've made commit but didn't sync it with remote repo. But when I try to sync it fails with `Failed to sync this branch - You might need to open a shell and debug the state of this repo`
I'm using Windows Git. Please, if you have any ideas why this happens  post here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Open a shell and debug the state of the repo

Comment: `git status`, `git remote show origin`, `git branch -vva`

Answer (score 0):

open a cmd terminal, go to the repo dir. Then try "git push origin < yourbranch>". See what error message you get. Without any more information about your setup it is hard to tell you anything more specific.